# How to get top N rows with some conditions

Tags: sql, sum, greatest-n-per-group, presto, amazon-athena

I have a query something like this:

```
SELECT product_id,
         site,
         category_id,
         session_time,
         sum(cast(coalesce("#clicks",
         0) AS bigint)) AS clicks
FROM df
WHERE site IN ('com', 'co')
        AND session_time = DATE('2020-02-27')
GROUP BY  product_id, site, session_time, category_id
ORDER BY clicks desc
LIMIT 10
```

But now, I want to see the **top 10 product_id** for each site and category_id based on the clicks. When I write the  LIMIT function, it only shows the top 10 products but it does not group it by category_id and shop_id.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions. You can `RANK()` records by descending `clicks` within `site`/`category` partitions  in a subquery, and then filter in the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        site,
        category_id,
        session_time,
        SUM("#clicks") clicks,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY site, category_id ORDER BY sum("#clicks") DESC) rn
    FROM df
    WHERE 
        site IN ('com', 'co')
        AND session_time = DATE('2020-02-27')
    GROUP BY  product_id, site, session_time, category_id
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY site, category, clicks desc
```

I am unclear on why you need the `coalesce()`/`cast()` logic in the `sum()` (just like other aggregate functions, `sum()` ignore `null` values, and it seems like `#clicks` is a number already), so I removed it - you can add it back if you do need it, for some reason that I could not think of.